# detect strange chars in csv python

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I have a CSV with a million line or so and some of the lines are mixed with some of these chars (meaning the line can be read but is mixed with baloney):

```
ªïÜÜµ+>&\ôowó¨ñø4(½;!|Nòdd¼Õõ¿¨W[¦¡¿p\,¶êÕMÜÙ;!ÂeÃ£YÃ3SÂ®Â´Ã¸ÂÃ
```

The input file is ISO-8859-1, each line filtered and written in an utf-8 new file.

can this be filtered? and how?

Here is what it looks like (the entire line)

```
Foo;Bar;24/01/2019-13:06;24/01/2019-12:55.01;;! 
ù:#ªïÜÜµ+>&\ôowó¨ñø4(½;!|Nòdd¼Õõ¿¨W[¦¡¿p\,¶êÕMÜÙ;! 
ÂeÃ£YÃ3ÃSÂ®Â´Ã¸ÂÃÃ§~ÂÂÂÂÃÃ½ÃÂ¬ÂÂ¯Ã£m;!ÃvÂ 
´Ã¼ÂÂ9Â¬uÂ»/"ÂFÃ|b`ÃÃÃµÃ Â±ÃÃÂ8ÃÂ;Baz
```

This is how i read it.
the encoding for fileObject being ISO-8859-1

```
def tee(self, rules=None):
    _good = open(self.good, "a")
    _bad = open(self.bad, "a")
    with open(self.temp, encoding=rules["encoding"]) as fileobject:
        cpt = 0
        _csv = csv.reader(fileobject, **self.dialect)
        for row in _csv:
            _len = len(row)
            _reconstructed = ";".join(row)
            self.count['original'] += 1
            if _len == rules["columns"]:
                _good.write("{}\n".format(_reconstructed))
            else:
                _bad.write("{}\n".format(_reconstructed))
                # print("[{}] {}:{}{}{}".format(_len, cpt, fg("red"), _reconstructed, attr("reset")))
                self.count['errors'] += 1
            cpt += 1
    _good.close()
    _bad.close()
```

Comment: Can you show how you are reading this in?

Comment: can you share your csv using this http://www.sharecsv.com/ ?

Comment: Can't share the csv , it contains sensitive client data. I edited the line i gave as an example but can't do more

Comment: Could you create a set of allowed characters and compare to them? Compare with ```char.lower()``` to reduce number of comparisons. Unless there's some pattern as to where they occur I'm not sure what else you could do. For example, do they only occur on certain lines?

Comment: @HoboProper Yes, only a few lines on the whole CSV. My client is a winter sports resort with clients from multiple countries, I suspect this is some Polish/Russian chars. I will try your solution and keep you posted.

Comment: You can build a filter: if 80% of chars are within 32 and 126 you have latin1, else something strange. But it seems you know you have a date, you can check where you have numbers (ASCII) and were garbage.